AWS CDK how to get subnet id by availability zone?
I can get the subnet ids for all the availability zones but I don't know how to get the subnet id for a specific availability zone.
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'VPC', {
  vpcId: vpcid,
});

const az1 = vpc.availabilityZones[0];

const privatesubnets = vpc.selectSubnets({availabilityZones: vpc.availabilityZones});

//subnetid1 is the subnet id in the first availability zone 
const subnetid1 = vpc.selectSubnets(availabilityZones: az1);

subnetid1 gives me error.
how do I get the subnet id only in availability zone 1?

const subnetid1 = vpc.selectSubnets({availabilityZones: [vpc.availabilityZones[0]]}).subnetIds[0];

